# How to get all elements by class name in Angular 8 from the typescript file

Tags: angular

I try to get all elements by class name  from HTML template,in the TS File.
This is what i tried so far.

```
 <div class="form-group" >
            <label class="name"  class="col-sm-2 control-label" [attr.for]="'skillName' + i">
              {{ arr[i]}} {{ i }}
            </label>
          </div>

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    let el = this.document.getElementsByClassName('name');
    console.log(el)
    console.log("*")
  }
```

Comment: And what is your question? Using the DOM in Angular is almost always a bad idea, because it goes against the principles of the framework. What is the concrete problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the Dom to access your element you should use ElementRef.

```
    // ...
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {}
    // ...
    const dom: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    const elements = dom.querySelectorAll('.name');
    console.log(elements);
```

But keep in mind, you should use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Use templating and data-binding or ViewChild and ViewChildren provided by Angular instead.

Comment: why should we use ViewChildren instead ? What is the benefit ?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
const el = document.querySelector('.myclass'); // first
const elArr = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass'); // all
```

The . is a selector for classes, see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: I forgot you want all, not just the first. Please try `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use angular's viewChild decorator for accessing the dom

**Html file**

```
<div class="form-group" >
                <label #labelRef class="name"  class="col-sm-2 control-label" [attr.for]="'skillName' + i">
                  {{ arr[i]}} {{ i }}
                </label>
              </div>
```

**component.ts file**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild('labelRef ', {static: false}) labelRef : ElementRef;

        ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.labelRef.nativeElement.innerHTML); 
        this.pRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = "DOM updated successfully!!!"; 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewChildren` as:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="name" #customLabel class="col-sm-2 control-label" [attr.for]="'skillName' + i">
        {{ arr[i]}} {{ i }}
    </label>
</div>

@ViewChildren('customLabel') labels: QueryList<ElementRef>

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.labels.forEach((label) => {
        console.log(label);
        // do whatever you want
    });
}
```

[Here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) is the reference for ViewChildren

Comment: "you should" is a stretch. What about dynamically added component, all kind of libraries etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const myHtmlEl = document.getElementsByClassName('my-style').item(0) as  HTMLElement;
        if (myHtmltEl) {
          myHtmltEl.style.display = 'none'; // for styling 
          myHtmltEl.click(); // for click event 
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
<p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in the document with class="example".</p>

<script>
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
        // Do stuff here
        el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try this script selection inside your typescript file. Their is no special selection option having for typescript.you can just use normal javascript syntax to achieve that.